# using json with [] and without []

Tags: ios, json

When i use json with [] (**like [{"ID":"1","name":"Amid","surname":"Nakano"}]**), i get this error. 
when use without [] (**{"ID":"1","name":"Amid","surname":"Nakano"}**) i dont get error;

### **Code is:**

**NSData *jsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://yrishi.com/site/test/json.json"]];

```
id jsonObjects = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
NSArray *keys = [jsonObjects allKeys];

// value in key name
//NSString *strMemberID = [jsonObjects objectForKey:@"MemberID"];
NSString *strName = [jsonObjects objectForKey:@"name"];
//NSString *strTel = [jsonObjects objectForKey:@"Tel"];
//NSLog(@"MemberID = %@",strMemberID);
NSLog(@"Name = %@",strName);
//NSLog(@"Tel = %@",strTel);

NSLog(@"====================");

// values in foreach loop
for (NSString *key in keys) {
    NSLog(@"%@ is %@",key, [jsonObjects objectForKey:key]);
```

### }**

**Error is:**

2015-03-09 00:43:34.146  iPhone Display Image on Table View from JSON URL[6738:193615] -[**NSArrayM allKeys]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fa002561ce0
2015-03-09 00:43:34.152  iPhone Display Image on Table View from JSON URL[6738:193615] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayM allKeys]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fa002561ce0'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000104229f35 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000103ec2bb7 objc_exception_throw + 45
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010423104d -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010418927c ___forwarding_** + 988
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000104188e18 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5    iPhone Display Image on Table View from JSON URL 0x00000001039962ab -[ViewController viewDidLoad] + 299
    6   UIKit                               0x000000010473ba90 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 738
    7   UIKit                               0x000000010473bc8e -[UIViewController view] + 27
    8   UIKit                               0x000000010465aca9 -[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] + 58
    9   UIKit                               0x000000010465b041 -[UIWindow _setHidden:forced:] + 247
    10  UIKit                               0x000000010466772c -[UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible] + 42
    11  UIKit                               0x0000000104612061 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 2628
    12  UIKit                               0x0000000104614d2c -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1350
    13  UIKit                               0x0000000104613bf2 -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 179
    14  FrontBoardServices                  0x0000000106de52a3 **31-[FBSSerialQueue performAsync:]_block_invoke + 16
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010415f53c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK** + 12
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000104155285 __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 341
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000104155045 __CFRunLoopRun + 2389
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000104154486 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
    19  UIKit                               0x0000000104613669 -[UIApplication _run] + 413
    20  UIKit                               0x0000000104616420 UIApplicationMain + 1282
    21   iPhone Display Image on Table View from JSON URL 0x0000000103996a63 main + 115
    22  libdyld.dylib                       0x00000001067b9145 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)

Answer (score 1):

In one case, the JSON data is an array containing a dictionary. In the other case, it is a dictionary. It should be obvious that your code with a call to allKeys isn't going to work (actually it is going to crash) if it is given an array and not a dictionary.

Comment: code is running with this: {"ID":"1","name":"Amid","surname":"Nakano"} when i am using [{"ID":"1","name":"Amid","surname":"Nakano"}] i get error